# Why when I copy a variable to window object it becomes public?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, global-variables

Regardless of the scope, if I create a variable and then pass it to (clone it) the window object it becomes public. A snippet of code speaks a thousand words:

```
(function(){
  var notCloned = false,
      toClone   = true;
  window.toClone = toClone;
}());
```

In this case I can access to `toClone`, `window.toClone`but not to `notCloned`.
Also I notice that they are binded in some way because any change you apply on one affects the other, e.g.:

```
window.toClone = false;
console.log(toClone); // It changes to false, too
```

Can anyone explain why and, also, how to keep `toClone`as a private (out of global scope) variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: everything defined on `window` is *global*. define it somewhere else to keep it out of global scope.

Comment: So, it can be understood as an alias?

Comment: @Bursos only if the rvalue is an object type - if it's a primitive (as you have) then it's not an alias

Comment: My guess is you executed the second snippet in the global scope, meaning `toClone` accessed it's value from the global scope rather than the local scope within the IIFE in your first snippet.

Comment: I don't understand why because I can't see any difference. I test with a object-type variable and has the same behaviour. Can you explain it more? @Alnitak

Comment: `console.log(toClone);` is not what you think it is. It is window.toClone, not the toClone inside the IFFE.

Comment: @Bursos what epascarello said.  You can't create an alias of primitives (because they're passed by value) - only objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference the global variable in your `console.log` statement.

Try this :

```
(function(){
  var notCloned = false,
      toClone   = true;
  window.toClone = toClone;
  window.whatsClone = function() { return toClone; }  
}());

window.toClone = false;
console.log(toClone);  // Will print false because actually is getting from the scope of global window
console.log(whatsClone()); // Will print true
```

`whatsClone()` will get the proper scoped variable.

I created fast [JSBin fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ninafekife/1/)

Also keep in mind that Primitives ( String, Number, Boolean ) are not referenced, they are copied, so basically:

```
foo = true;
window.bar = foo;
```

`window.bar` will not be a reference to `foo` it will be just a copy of the boolean value.

Comment: Nice, it's like *scopenception* This piece of code resolves my trouble! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`window` is an object that is also initial "context" for all functions.

If you write some code in JavaScript without using scope-changing patterns, i. e. `bind()`, `apply()` or classes, your default scope will be `window`. Anything defined without `var` keyword or explicitly set as `window` property will be visible *everywhere* in your script.